# Ajax invalidating viewstate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

This seems to be a pretty common question. But I have not yet found a post where the basic issue is addressed.

I have a heavily ajaxed application and I am running into this. 
In a nutshell, the ASPX page is litle more than a series of divs that are populated w/ HTML by AJAX calls. 
If anyone has comments on these basic questions I would greatly appreciate it. I will begin a sample app and see if I can answer them as well.

1. Does the removal of `runat=server` controls w/ Ajax cause this.
2. If i populate a DIV w/ the HTML that is generated by a `runat=server` control , will that trigger this.
3. Is there a way to lobotomize a `runat=server` control before returning it as part of an ajax ctl.

( For example - a repeater is really nice to build a table. Can i use the repeater and then remove some syntax from the HTML before I send the response to the client. 
I can do the looping if i have to..
)

4)  Is there something I can put in the header to make this whole thing go away.

```
Page Language="vb" 
AutoEventWireup="false" 
CodeBehind="frustration.aspx.vb"                       
_Inherits="Portal.frustration"
EnableViewState="false"   
enableViewStateMAC="false"  
EnableEventValidation="false" 
ValidateRequest="false"
ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" 
MasterPageFile="~/_MasterPages/Admin.Master"
```

Thanks, 
greg.

Comment: If you're going to use ajax, just use ajax. Mixing it in with postbacks without actually knowing what you're doing will end ugly.

Comment: I am not sure how you are using ajax to populate your html. But just make sure that HTML in your ajax response does not have a viewstate field in it. And also make sure that the viewstate of current page is not being overwritten/modified by ajax response. This will usually happen when you are dumping another page's html entirely into your current [age

Comment: You need to locate what you change and you break the page, or what you did not send together with the page. You can start disable some viewstate on most of your controls and make some tries to locate what you break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it to work, but I'm abandoning the .NET menu anyway. 
Since I was looking for some high level information, I will let the community what I was able to do...

The viewstate issue happens when I load the AJAX page then navigate using the menu. It happens because clicking the menu posts back to my AJAX page before it navigates away. If it were just a hyperlink, there would be no issue.

The AJAX page in question is essentially 3 divs. 
Div_A is a navigation element consisting of a list of documents. 
Div_B is a read only detail of 1 document w/ some action buttons.
Div_C is an input form.
The divs are populated by jQUery ajax calls. On success, I replace the entire innerHTML of the DIV in question.
Div_A  & Div_B  are automatically populated at page load in that order. (List and first document detail)

Breaking things down, just populating Div_A caused the problem. 
Inspection showed that I had some DIVs w/ RUNAT=SERVER. I removed that. This did not resolve the problem.
There was also a FORM around the entire content. The form was tagged runat=server.
I removed the FORM completely. This allowed me to use the menu without the viewstate error. However, If i clicked a second document, causing  Div_B to reload. The problem reoccurred.

Div_B had the same FORM surrounding everything. (These must have be placed automatically by Visual Studio. There is no reason to have either form as both DIV_A and DIV_B are readonly) 
The interesting thing about DIV_B is that there are DIVs with RUNAT=SERVER that I need because I set the innerText in the code behind. 
Removing the FORM allowed me to navigate between documents and still be able to use the menu without VIEWSTATE errors.

So : 
Having RUNAT=SERVER HTML elements added to a page DOES NOT seem to break VIEWSTATE
Having a RUNAT=SERVER FORM added to a page DOES seem to break VIEWSTATE.

So things are back to working, but why did this problem crop up suddenly? Not sure. Much has changed and I can't point to any 1 thing. (Maybe the FORMs got autogenerated when I upgraded from vs10->vs12). Who knows, who cares...

Ultimately - I can't continue to coddle this problem just for the sake of the .NET menu item. To @Brad M's point, I have decided to just use a jQuery menu and that will eliminate any wholesale page postbacks to this page.

A little searching and I uncovered arnab_bandyopadhyays' implementation of a horizontal jQuery menu which he demonstrates here: http://jsfiddle.net/yRJ9g/.

```
<<stackoverflow wants some code if i reference jsfiddle, so here ya go...>>
dim viewStateWorksWellWAjax as boolean =false
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Greg